# SharePoint 2013 permission level

Tags: sharepoint-online, synchronisation

Is it possible to create access / permission level where user can view / create / upload files Online, but not sync a folder / library?

Comment: No, the sync proces is an automated proces of what a user can do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but the alternative is to go to the library and go into the *Library Settings*. From there go to the *Advanced Settings* and scroll down to *Offline Client Availability*. Set this to *No* and click **OK**.

This will block all users from being able to sync that particular library.

Comment: Thanks :) it works .. but if I want to set the permissions for stopping a folder in the library to sync but it should be visible in the Web ... is it possible ?

Comment: Disabling syncing should have no impact on the folder visibility

Comment: If I have 3 folders in the document library
FOLDER  A
FOLDER B
FOLDER C

and  Offline Client Availability YES (default ) but will not allow  FOLDER A in the document library from syncas but everything else syncas as usual , it is possible ? 
Thanks again